# Error en conexión con mysql con java

Tags: java, mysql

Amigos intente hacer una conexion con mysql con java y me intente confirmar a través de la consola que no hubiera nada pero esta me devuelve lo siguiente mientras que en el IDE no me registra ningún tipo de error.

```
package servicios;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


/**
 *
 * @author SS
 */
public class Conexion {
    private Connection con;
    public Conexion(){

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smartprice?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("Error: "+ e);
    }catch(SQLException e){
    System.err.println("Error: "+ e);
    }

}
    public Connection getConexion(){
        return con;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
    }
}

error:
```

ant -f "C:\Users\SS\Documents\SOFTWARE\Practica\web\java web\login" -Djavac.includes=servicios/Conexion.java -Dnb.internal.action.name=debug.single -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false "-Dbrowser.context=C:\Users\SS\Documents\SOFTWARE\Practica\web\java web\login\src\java\servicios\Conexion.java" -Ddebug.class=servicios.Conexion debug-single-main
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
compile-single:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at servicios.Conexion.main(Conexion.java:1)
Java Result: 1
debug-single-main:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

¿que es y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Coloque el código fuente de la clase Conexion.

Comment: ¿Ese es el mensaje de error completo: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at servicios.Conexion.main(Conexion.java:1)
Java Result: 1` o dice más cosas? Si hay más cosas pon el mensaje de error completo en la pregunta aunque sea largo.